A generic mapping class targeting many job source
Problem
The challenge is to create a flexible system for mapping job data from various external sources (such as Workable) into a standardised internal format. The system needed to handle:

Diverse data structures from different job platforms
Inconsistent field naming and value formats
Conversion between different data types (e.g., strings to enums, timestamps to datetime objects)
Mapping of varying terminology to standardized internal enums (e.g., job statuses, contract types)

Solution
I have tried to implement a configurable mapping system using Pydantic models, which allows for:

Definition of source-specific data mappings
Automatic data validation and type conversion
Custom transformation functions for complex field mappings
Extensibility to easily add new data sources or fields

Code
from enum import Enum
from typing import Any
from datetime import datetime
from decimal import Decimal


from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


RawData = dict[str, Any]


class TransformType(str, Enum):
    TO_INT = "to_int"
    TO_FLOAT = "to_float"
    TO_STR = "to_str"
    TO_DECIMAL = "to_decimal"
    TO_DATETIME = "to_datetime"
    TO_JOB_STATUS = "to_job_status"
    TO_CONTRACT_TYPE = "to_contract_type"
    TO_JOB_SOURCE = "to_job_source"
    TO_EXPERIENCE_LEVEL = "to_experience_level"
    TO_EDUCATION_LEVEL = "to_education_level"


class JobStatus(str, Enum):
    SCHEDULED = "SCHEDULED"
    ACTIVE = "ACTIVE"
    CLOSED = "CLOSED"
    ARCHIVED = "ARCHIVED"


class JobContractType(str, Enum):
    FULL_TIME = "FULL_TIME"
    PART_TIME = "PART_TIME"
    CONTRACT = "CONTRACT"


class JobSource(str, Enum):
    REGISTERED_ORG = "REGISTERED_ORG"
    MANUALLY_ENTERED = "MANUALLY_ENTERED"
    JOB_IMPORTER = "JOB_IMPORTER"
    TEST_DATA = "TEST_DATA"
    BREEZY_HR = "BREEZY_HR"
    WORKABLE = "WORKABLE"


class JobExperienceLevel(str, Enum):
    INTERN = "INTERN"
    JUNIOR = "JUNIOR"
    MID = "MID"
    SENIOR = "SENIOR"
    LEAD = "LEAD"
    HEAD = "HEAD"
    C_SUITE = "C_SUITE"


class JobEducationLevel(str, Enum):
    NO_FORMAL_EDUCATION = "NO_FORMAL_EDUCATION"
    GCSE = "GCSE"
    A_LEVEL = "A_LEVELS"
    FOUNDATION_DEGREE = "FOUNDATION_DEGREE"
    BACHELOR_DEGREE = "BACHELOR_DEGREE"
    POSTGRADUATE_DIPLOMA = "POSTGRADUATE_DIPLOMA"
    MASTER_DEGREE = "MASTER_DEGREE"
    DOCTORATE_DEGREE = "DOCTORATE_DEGREE"


class FieldMapping(BaseModel):
    path: str | None = None
    default: Any = None
    transform: TransformType | None = None


class ConnectorMapping(BaseModel):
    __root__: dict[str, str | FieldMapping]


class MappingConfig(BaseModel):
    __root__: dict[str, ConnectorMapping]


class JobMapping(BaseModel):

    WORKABLE: dict[str, Any] = {
        "title": "title",
        "description": {
            "path": "description",
            "default": "No description provided"
        },
        "salary_max": {
            "path": "salary.salary_to",
            "transform": TransformType.TO_DECIMAL
        },
        "salary_min": {
            "path": "salary.salary_from",
            "transform": TransformType.TO_DECIMAL
        },
        "salary_currency": "salary.salary_currency",
        "contract_type": {
            "path": "location.workplace_type",
            "transform": TransformType.TO_CONTRACT_TYPE
        },
        "salary_negotiable": {
            # Workable doesn't provide this information directly, so set a default
            "default": False
        },
        "responsibilities": "description",
        "department": "department",
        "url": "url",
        "application_url": "application_url",
        "source": {
            "default": "WORKABLE",
            "transform": TransformType.TO_JOB_SOURCE
        },
        "sector": {
            "path": "department",  # Using department as a proxy for sector
            "transform": TransformType.TO_STR
        },
        "location": "location.location_str",
        "latlng": {
            "path": "location",
            "transform": TransformType.TO_STR
        },
        "scheduled_on_date": {
            "path": "created_at",
            "transform": TransformType.TO_DATETIME
        },
        "closing_on_date": {
            "default": None  # Workable doesn't provide this directly
        },
        "published_on_date": {
            "path": "created_at",  # Using created_at as a proxy for published date
            "transform": TransformType.TO_DATETIME
        },
        "external_reference_id": "id",
    }


class ExternalJob(BaseModel):

    title: str
    description: str | None = None
    salary_max: Decimal
    contract_type: JobContractType
    salary_negotiable: bool = False
    vacancy_count: int = 1
    status: JobStatus = JobStatus.ACTIVE
    responsibilities: str | None = None
    experience_level: JobExperienceLevel | None = None
    salary_min: Decimal | None = None
    education_level: JobEducationLevel | None = None
    department: str | None = None
    url: str | None = None
    source: JobSource
    sector: str | None = None
    location: str | None = None
    latlng: str | None = None
    scheduled_on_date: datetime | None = None
    closing_on_date: datetime | None = None
    published_on_date: datetime | None = None
    external_reference_id: str | None = None

    @classmethod
    def from_raw(cls, raw_data: dict[str, Any], mapping: dict[str, Any]):

        mapped_data = {}
        for field, field_mapping in mapping.items():
            if isinstance(field_mapping, str):
                mapped_data[field] = cls.get_nested_value(raw_data, field_mapping)

            elif isinstance(field_mapping, dict):
                value = (
                    cls.get_nested_value(raw_data, field_mapping.get('path'))
                    if field_mapping.get('path')
                    else field_mapping.get('default')
                )
                if field_mapping.get('transform'):
                    value = cls.apply_transform(value, field_mapping['transform'])

                mapped_data[field] = value

        return cls(**mapped_data)


    @staticmethod
    def get_nested_value(data: RawData, path: str | None) -> Any:
        if not path:
            return None

        keys = path.split('.')
        value = data
        for key in keys:
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                value = value.get(key, {})
            else:
                return None

        return value if value != {} else None

    @staticmethod
    def apply_transform(value: Any, transform: TransformType) -> Any | None:
        if value is None:
            return None

        match transform:
            case TransformType.TO_INT:
                return int(value)
            case TransformType.TO_FLOAT:
                return float(value)
            case TransformType.TO_STR:
                if isinstance(value, dict) and 'latitude' in value and 'longitude' in value:
                    return f"{value.get('latitude', 0)},{value.get('longitude', 0)}"
                return str(value)
            case TransformType.TO_DECIMAL:
                return Decimal(str(value))
            case TransformType.TO_DATETIME:
                return datetime.fromisoformat(value.rstrip('Z'))
            case TransformType.TO_CONTRACT_TYPE:
                contract_mapping = {
                    "full_time": JobContractType.FULL_TIME,
                    "part_time": JobContractType.PART_TIME,
                    "contract": JobContractType.CONTRACT
                }
                return contract_mapping.get(value.lower(), JobContractType.FULL_TIME)
            case TransformType.TO_JOB_SOURCE:
                return JobSource(value.upper())
            case _:
                return None

Entry Point
if __name__ == "__main__":
    workable_data = {
        "id": "1234",
        "title": "Software Engineer",
        "full_title": "Senior Software Engineer - Backend",
        "shortcode": "SE001",
        "state": "published",
        "department": "Engineering",
        "url": "https://example.com/jobs/se001",
        "application_url": "https://example.com/apply/se001",
        "shortlink": "https://wrbl.in/se001",
        "location": {
            "location_str": "New York, NY, United States",
            "country": "United States",
            "country_code": "US",
            "region": "New York",
            "region_code": "NY",
            "city": "New York",
            "zip_code": "10001",
            "telecommuting": False,
            "workplace_type": "on_site"
        },
        "salary": {
            "salary_from": 80000,
            "salary_to": 120000,
            "salary_currency": "USD"
        },
        "created_at": "2023-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "department_hierarchy": [
            {"id": 1, "name": "Technology"},
            {"id": 2, "name": "Engineering"}
        ]
    }

    mapping =  JobMapping()
    workable_mapper = mapping.WORKABLE
    job_model = ExternalJob.from_raw(workable_data, workable_mapper)
    print(job_model.json(indent=2))

Result
{
  "title": "Software Engineer",
  "description": null,
  "salary_max": 120000,
  "contract_type": "FULL_TIME",
  "salary_negotiable": false,
  "vacancy_count": 1,
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "responsibilities": null,
  "experience_level": null,
  "salary_min": 80000,
  "education_level": null,
  "department": "Engineering",
  "url": "https://example.com/jobs/se001",
  "source": "WORKABLE",
  "sector": "Engineering",
  "location": "New York, NY, United States",
  "latlng": "{'location_str': 'New York, NY, United States', 'country': 'United States', 'country_code': 'US', 'region': 'New York', 'region_code': 'NY', 'city': 'New York', 'zip_code': '10001', 'telecommuting': False, 'workplace_type': 'on_site'}",
  "scheduled_on_date": "2023-01-01T00:00:00",
  "closing_on_date": null,
  "published_on_date": "2023-01-01T00:00:00",
  "external_reference_id": "1234"
}

Self Analysis

from_raw & get_nested_value feel pretty complex - am I re-inventing the wheel? Surely there are methods I can call into via Pydantic.
apply_transform(...) smells. It feels like I should probably have a custom to_dict() instance method or a custom JSON encoder that based of json.JSONEncoder
No Doc-strings
No error handling. It doesn't adequately deal with scenarios where expected fields are missing or in unexpected formats.

References:

Pydantic
Workable Job API


Are you sure it is not easier to just write a parser to parse the raw data? You will need to write some code for each api either way; why choose to write a mapping config and not just normal code?
You also lost the ability to process the data.
class ExternalJob(BaseModel):     
    title                 : str
    source                : JobSource
    salary_max            : Decimal
    contract_type         : JobContractType
    vacancy_count         : int                          = 1
    salary_negotiable     : bool                         = False
    status                : JobStatus                    = JobStatus.ACTIVE
    experience_level      : Optional[JobExperienceLevel] = None
    salary_min            : Optional[Decimal]            = None
    education_level       : Optional[JobEducationLevel]  = None
    description           : Optional[str]                = None
    responsibilities      : Optional[str]                = None
    department            : Optional[str]                = None
    url                   : Optional[str]                = None
    sector                : Optional[str]                = None
    location              : Optional[str]                = None
    latlng                : Optional[str]                = None
    external_reference_id : Optional[str]                = None
    scheduled_on_date     : Optional[datetime]           = None
    closing_on_date       : Optional[datetime]           = None
    published_on_date     : Optional[datetime]           = None


class WorkableParser:
    contract_mapping = {
        "full_time" : JobContractType.FULL_TIME,
        "part_time" : JobContractType.PART_TIME,
        "contract"  : JobContractType.CONTRACT
    }

    def GBP_to_USD(gbp: float) -> float:
        gbp * 1.34

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, raw_data: RawData) -> ExternalJob:
        job = {}

        job["title"] = raw_data["title"]
        job["source"] = JobSource.WORKABLE
        job["salary_max"] = raw_data["salary"]["salary_to"]
        job["contract_type"] = cls.contract_mapping.get(raw_data["location"]["workplace_type"].lower(), JobContractType.FULL_TIME)
        # other fields . . .
        # .
        # .
        # .

        # What if you want to extract data from another field of the raw data
        if raw_data["location"]["country_code"] == "UK":
            job["salary_max"] = cls.GBP_to_USD(job["salary_max"])

        # What if you want to do some more complex data extraction 
        full_title = raw_data["full_title"].lower()
        if "senior" in full_title:
            job["experience_level"] = JobExperienceLevel.SENIOR
        elif "junior" in full_title:
            job["experience_level"] = JobExperienceLevel.JUNIOR
        elif "intern" in full_title:
            job["experience_level"] = JobExperienceLevel.INTERN

        return ExternalJob(**job)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    workable_data = {
        "id": "1234",
        "title": "Software Engineer",
        "full_title": "Senior Software Engineer - Backend",
        "shortcode": "SE001",
        "state": "published",
        "department": "Engineering",
        "url": "https://example.com/jobs/se001",
        "application_url": "https://example.com/apply/se001",
        "shortlink": "https://wrbl.in/se001",
        "location": {
            "location_str": "New York, NY, United States",
            "country": "United States",
            "country_code": "US",
            "region": "New York",
            "region_code": "NY",
            "city": "New York",
            "zip_code": "10001",
            "telecommuting": False,
            "workplace_type": "on_site"
        },
        "salary": {
            "salary_from": 80000,
            "salary_to": 120000,
            "salary_currency": "USD"
        },
        "created_at": "2023-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "department_hierarchy": [
            {"id": 1, "name": "Technology"},
            {"id": 2, "name": "Engineering"}
        ]
    }
    workable_job = WorkableParser.parse(workable_data)

    print(workable_job.model_dump_json(indent=2))

{
  "title": "Software Engineer",
  "source": "WORKABLE",
  "salary_max": "120000",
  "contract_type": "FULL_TIME",
  "vacancy_count": 1,
  "salary_negotiable": false,
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "experience_level": "SENIOR",
  "salary_min": null,
  "education_level": null,
  "description": null,
  "responsibilities": null,
  "department": null,
  "url": null,
  "sector": null,
  "location": null,
  "latlng": null,
  "external_reference_id": null,
  "scheduled_on_date": null,
  "closing_on_date": null,
  "published_on_date": null
}


This is a good point. If I am already going to the trouble of writing a mapper, why not just maintain a parser. Thanks the new perspective. I'm marking this as the answer as its what I am going to use.
